git p4 clone - failure accessing depot: could not run p4
I am having trouble cloning a Perforce depot using git p4 clone.
I am running the following command:
git p4 clone //depot/systems@all

I get the following error:

Initialized empty Git repository in /folder/folder/.git/
Perforce client error:
p4 -h for usage.
Invalid option: -r.
failure accessing depot: could not run p4

Running p4 depots I can see the following:
Depot systems 2010/12/03 local systems/... 'Created by user. '

I am able to sync / add and edit into Perforce without issue.
I'm not sure where I am going wrong.
I'm running RH 9.4 and python 3.9. I've also tried a p4 login before running the git p4 clone
Running git p4 clone with verbose shows the following error:
    Initialized empty Git repository in /u/brazilb/systems/.git/
Reading pipe: git config --bool git-p4.useclientspec
Reading pipe: git config git-p4.user
Reading pipe: git config git-p4.password
Reading pipe: git config git-p4.port
Reading pipe: git config git-p4.host
Reading pipe: git config git-p4.client
Reading pipe: git config --int git-p4.retries
Reading pipe: git config --int git-p4.retries
Opening pipe: p4 -r 3 -G login -s
Perforce client error:
        p4 -h for usage.
        Invalid option: -r.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/u/brazilb/bin/git-p4.py", line 4628, in <module>
    main()
  File "/u/brazilb/bin/git-p4.py", line 4622, in main
    if not cmd.run(args):
  File "/u/brazilb/bin/git-p4.py", line 4367, in run
    if not P4Sync.run(self, depotPaths):
  File "/u/brazilb/bin/git-p4.py", line 4221, in run
    p4_check_access()
  File "/u/brazilb/bin/git-p4.py", line 475, in p4_check_access
    results = p4CmdList(["login", "-s"])
  File "/u/brazilb/bin/git-p4.py", line 864, in p4CmdList
    cmd = p4_build_cmd(["-G"] + cmd)
  File "/u/brazilb/bin/git-p4.py", line 140, in p4_build_cmd
    p4_check_access()
  File "/u/brazilb/bin/git-p4.py", line 485, in p4_check_access
    die_bad_access("could not run p4")
  File "/u/brazilb/bin/git-p4.py", line 469, in die_bad_access
    die("failure accessing depot: {0}".format(s.rstrip()))
  File "/u/brazilb/bin/git-p4.py", line 193, in die
    raise Exception(msg)
Exception: failure accessing depot: could not run p4


If your depot is called systems then the path to it would be //systems, not //depot/systems.  I'm not sure if that explains why git is trying to run a command with entirely the wrong global flag though.

This fixed it for me:
git config --global git-p4.retries 0

Provide a way to not pass this option by setting git-p4.retries to 0.

Your p4 command line client is too old to support the -r option.
